# Data is not storing in database? I'm using python and pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, python-3.8

My code is given below. Everything is working fine and no error, but I am not able to store the data in database permanently it store temporarily for some reason. the data is deleted or gone (where I don't no) when ever program fully executes its self. The last loop is for fetching the data from same table and its show the data that is entered in the table at the end of program.

The weird thing is that the id of table is increase by number of data on every insertion.

The database doesn't response  during debugging after the data insertion and then after some time response like in

[image: database error]

pic database error  try:

```
    #Storing Data using same procedure
    for address in ADDRESSES:
        variables = (address["appname"],address["address"])
        conn.execute("{call SP_Update_Addresses (?,?)}",variables)

    #Fetching data from same table using store procedure
    result = conn.execute("exec dbo.show")
    for r in result:
        print(r)
```

After execution that piece of code the data is gone. But it show the table data in the pycharm terminal.
One more thing, I even tried passing the SQL query instead of stored procedure but the problem is there
try:

```
    Sql_Udating = '''INSERT INTO dbo.App_Indexing (App_Name,Address) values (?,?)'''
    #Storing Data using sql query
    for address in ADDRESSES:

        variables = (address["appname"],address["address"])
        conn.execute(Sql_Udating,variables)

    #Fetching data from same table using sql query
    result = conn.execute('''select * from dbo.App_Indexing''')
    for r in result:
        print(r)
```

Comment: Have you read [Database Transaction Management](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Database-Transaction-Management) yet? Autocommit defaults to false.

Comment: No, i will study now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

engine = "mssql+pyodbc://your_server_name/your_database_name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"

# some kind of processing here, or loop, or whatever you do to create your dataframe...    

df.to_sql(x, engine, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

df = name of your dataframe
x = name you want to give to your table in SQL Server